# What framework can i use to create gmail-client iphone application?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, pantomime

I've tried MailCore - have a problem with "library not linked" "reason - image not found"/ adding new copy file build phaze doesn't solve it; tried to use pantomime but have over 1000 errors with `#include <Pantomime/Somefile.h>` (i changed all this `#include <Pantomime/Somefile.h>` for `#import "Somefile.h"`) its becouse a i used not a framework but an open-source library;
and i tried to add EDMessage framework - but i think it's for cocoa but not for cocoa touch becouse i had an error with NSCalendarDate. i can't use MessageUI becouse i need a full client to receive and send messages.

Answer (score 2):

Pantomime is too big and not well documented. You can try:

- [MailCore](http://www.mronge.com/m/MailCore/API/) (it works, check how are you including it)
- libetpan, plain c, low level, it's the underlying library in MailCore (last time I checked)
- [letters](https://github.com/ccgus/letters), Cocoa, IIRC requires blocks

Comment: ok,if you can,please send we ready x-code iphone project with included MailCore (window-based application),because my mailcore-project compiling but no running...askona1@gmail.com tar or zip

Comment: I tried to include MailCore by dragging MailCore.framework, it appeared every place it should and i`ve added new copy file phase but it`s not working

Comment: iPhone can't use normal frameworks, you need a static library or just use the source directly

Comment: what static library can i use? when i used a source pantomime i had a lot of errors i really dont know what to do, i f*cked my brain for a 3 days on my job i`m panic!

Comment: MailCore includes a static library target called "MailCore iPhone".

Comment: i found mailcore iphone but what can i do with it?
http://i061.radikal.ru/1011/8f/dc4349103b9b.jpg - it`s screenshot from my files pane.
in build folder i did`n find anything useful...
how can i get this static library and use it?please mooore information..

Comment: if you can write me in skype - askona75